# Make Three Js 2D Game Responsive

Tags: three.js

**Hello Community**,

I am New in Three Js.I am Creating 2D Game With Three JS and I am facing Some issue to make Game Responsive and also when Size of the game play is decrease some functionalities are not working properly like touch event on object.I want to know that can we apply css to the three js objects so that we can create the responsive desing game.

Please Guide me about it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your camera and renderer to the window size from the start and then add an event listener that will alter properties of objects that relate to the screen size. Usually something like this:

```
// keep track of the window size in an object
const size = { width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight };

// initialize camera based on recorded sizes
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  size.width / size.height,
  0.1,
  100
);
camera.position.set(...);
scene.add(camera);

// initialize renderer based on recorded sizes
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
renderer.setSize(size.width, size.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(2, window.devicePixelRatio));


// adjust relevant properties on window size change
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  size.width = window.innerWidth;
  size.height = window.innerHeight;
  camera.aspect = size.width / size.height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(size.width, size.height);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(2, window.devicePixelRatio));
});
```

Hopefully this is the answer you're looking for.